# geom_tile - draw empty tiles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a black border for every tile even though my data set is  missing values for some combinations of x and y

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(10)
df = data.frame(x=factor(sample(1:5, 5)), y=factor(sample(1:5, 5)), z=factor(sample(1:5, 5)))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + geom_tile(size=0.5, color="black")
```

[image]

It will work if I fill NA for the missing xy values. Also, the legend now shows the "NA" label, which I want to hide.

Is there a way to draw every tiles without filling in NA?

```
# fill in NA for missing combinations of x and y before drawing geom_tile
df2 = df %>% complete(x,y)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + geom_tile(size=0.5, color="black") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1", na.value="white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm finding other SO posts about removing `NA` from legends by just filtering out the `NA` rows. In this case, it's clearly *intentional* that those `NA`s are there. Instead, you can set the breaks for the fill scale to include just the numbers you need and not the `NA`s.

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile(size = 0.5, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.value = "white", breaks = 1:5)
```

[image]

If you need something more robust, like if the z-scale isn't just a simple count of 1 to 5, you could pull out a vector of unique values to for variable, excluding `NA`, and pass that to the `breaks` argument.

Comment: Is there a way to draw all the tiles if you just use df (which doesn't have the NA filled in)

Comment: I'm not sure how you would tell it where to place tiles if they're not in the data. You could hack together a bunch of `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` calls, or put the gridlines on top of the geoms by messing around with `panel.ontop` in `theme`...but I can't imagine either of those working better or more neatly than `tidyr::complete`